# ios tableviewcell several objects one a cell programatically , setting prototype cell programatically , custom table view cell style,

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, prototype

hello I built this tableview using the InterfaceBuilder  and storyboard   I used custom for the style of the  cell  and content prototype of the table view, this is the image:
 [custom tableview](http://i50.tinypic.com/23k421g.png)

but now I need to redo everything programmatically    I tried insert an imageview in the cell using this code

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
  CGRectMake(300, 0, 80, 80)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"esquina_estrella.png"];
cell.imageView.image = imgView.image;`
```

but the image stays static unresponsive to CGRectMake  thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to the Cell:

```
// Make your frame origin 0,0 as below done.
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];

imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"esquina_estrella.png"];

[cell addSubview:imgView];
[imgView release]; 
imgView = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

To limit display of the image to the frame of the image view.

Also, you are adding the image of the image view to the cell's image view, which is a different object, without using your image view and its frame. You actually do not need an image view if you are just using the image. What you want is

```
cell.imageView = imgView;
```

or

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
```

The latter will be preferable if you want to place it exactly and add more image views as in your screen shot.